# openstack installation single node

Tags: linux, installation, openstack

I am trying a single node installation of openstack.
I have a HP blade , over which ubuntu server 14.04 is installed.
i have created an open virtual switch and a virtual port.i follwed the below link to set up KVM .
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/libvirt.html .
I have to create another VM on the KVM for the controller which has to have the ubuntu server as well. I have mounted the iso file on to a folder currently. I am stuck after this point. i need direction on how to create a VM over this KVM and load the ubuntu server over it. Any help would be greatly appriciated

Answer (score -1):

Here is the list of step to create KVM machine with OVS.

**Installing KVM**

1. Check if KVM is supported on the Machine.

   egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo

> output: should return greater than 0 if KVM is supported.

2. Check the if 64bit Kernel

   egrep -c ' lm ' /proc/cpuinfo

> output: should return greater than 0 if its 64bit Kernel

3. Install KVM and related dependencies

   ```
    sudo apt-get install qemu-kvm libvirt-bin ubuntu-vm-builder virtinst bridge-utils uml-utilities
   ```
4. Add current user to libvert

   ```
   sudo adduser $USER libvirtd
   ```
5. Verify if installation was sucessful

   ```
   virsh -c qemu:///system list
   ```

> output:Should return empty list and not any error.

**Default configuration locations**

- Default directory: `/var/lib/libvirt/`
- ISO images for installation: `/var/lib/libvirt/boot/`
- VM installation directory: `/var/lib/libvirt/images/`
- Libvirt configuration directory for LVM/LXC/qemu: `/etc/libvirt/`

6. By default 'default' network would be created by libvirt, check if its present.

   ```
       sudo virsh net-list
   ```
7. To view the network info.

   ```
       sudo virsh net-info default
       or
       sudo virsh net-dumpxml default
   ```
8. By default VNC runs on localhost, change the configuration such that it could be remotely accessed.

> Edit /etc/libvirt/qemu.conf

```
vnc_listen = "0.0.0.0"
```

This will enable connections from all hosts,

> Edit /etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf

```
listen_tcp = 1
```

9. Check if the ports used by vnc and libvirt are open. In the case you are using firewall:

   ```
   sudo ufw status verbose
   ```
10. Reboot system
11. Create a VM

    ```
    sudo virt-install \
    --name kp-devstack \
    --ram 1524 \
    --vcpus=4 \
    --os-variant=linux \
    --virt-type kvm \
    --cdrom=ubuntu-16.04-server-amd64.iso \
    --network network=default,model=virtio \
    --graphics vnc \
    --disk path=/home/kprasad/images/ububtu64.img,size=25,bus=virtio
    ```

> Set RAM greater than 2GB provided VM is 64bit
>
> Set virt-type to kvm if kvm is supported else qemu other option is xen.
>
> you can set network to default or to tap shown in later part to use ovs

**Installation of GuestVM.**

1. Check vnc ip and port

   ```
   sudo virsh dumpxml kp-devstack | grep vnc
   ```
2. Connect to VNC server

   a. if your ubuntu machine has gui you can use vnc client

   b. if you want to connect to vnc server from windows you can use real vnc

   [readlVNC](https://archive.realvnc.com/download/open/)

   c. In Server textbox give the ip address of the ubuntu machine one which vm is installed in following format

   ```
   <ip-address:<port>
   ```
3. On click of 'OK' a window shall open.
4. Continue with installation of GuestVM(if qemu is hyper-visor installation process will be painstakingly slow)
5. Once installation is complete machine shall be restarted.
6. Login to VNC again.
7. Login to virtual machine.
8. Check the ip address assigned from default network
9. Now you can use ssh to login to virtual machine from parent ubuntu machine.

**Installation and setting up of Openvswitch**

1. Install dependencies

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openvswitch-common openvswitch-pki openvswitch-dbg openvswitch-switch openvswitch-ipsec openvswitch-switch-dpdk openvswitch-vtep openvswitch-switch
   ```
2. Generally two or more nics are assigned in cloud environment, in most cases there shall be atleast 2 nics one for management and other for data network. Assuming eth0 for management network and eth1 for datanetwork.

> Edit /etc/network/interfaces file set eth1 iface load to manual

```
   auto eth1
   iface eth1 inet manual
```

3. Create Bridge

   ```
    sudo ovs-vsctl add-br br0
   ```
4. Add eth1 interface to bridge

   ```
    sudo ovs-vsctl add-port br0 eth1
   ```

**Creation of Openvswitch network for libvirt**

1. Create a xml file to be loaded to libvirt

   ```
   <network>
      <name>ovs-net</name>
      <forward mode='bridge'/>
      <bridge name='br0'/>
      <virtualport type='openvswitch' />
   </network>
   ```
2. Create Network using the xml

   ```
   sudo virsh net-create kp-ovs.xml
   ```
3. Check if network is sucessfully created

   ```
   sudo virsh net-dumpxml ovs-net
   ```

**Creating a NIC and attaching to VM**

1. List Interfaces attached to VM

   ```
    sudo virsh domiflist kp-devstack
   ```
2. Attach the nic with OVS network

   ```
    sudo virsh attach-interface --domain kp-devstack --type network --source ovs-net --model virtio --config --live
   ```
3. Verify nic is created

   ```
    sudo virsh domiflist kp-devstack
   ```
4. The second nic created also should be visible in openvswitch

   ```
    sudo ovs-vsctl show
   ```
5. ssh virtual machine
6. Check if the second nic is added

   ```
    sudo ifconfig -a
   ```
7. if the nic is added sucessfully, bring it up

   ```
       sudo ifconfig eth1 up
   ```

8 Assign ip address using dhcp

```
    sudo ifconfig eth1 0
    sudo dhclient eth1
```

9. Alternatively you can set static IP.

**Deleting VM**

```
virsh list --all
virsh destroy kp-devstack
virsh undefine kp-devstack
virsh vol-list --pool
virsh vol-delete --pool images ububtu64.img
```